# java6 not being reused when creating two similar images

Tags: docker

I am following the examples in book 'Docker in Action' chapter 3.

> Here are the commands you should run:
>
> ***docker pull dockerinaction/ch3_myapp***
>
> ***docker pull dockerinaction/ch3_myotherapp***

The two images' Dockerfile look exact the same in docker hub, as below.

```
FROM java:6
COPY . /example
WORKDIR /example

RUN adduser --system --no-create-home --disabled-password --disabled-login --shell /bin/sh example
RUN chown example /example
RUN chown example /example/*
USER example

RUN javac Main.java
CMD ["java", "Main"]
```

I think the example is trying to say that the first pull command takes longer due to downloading java6 and its dependencies, and the second pull command will take much shorter time since the first command has already downloaded them. However, after running the commands, it looks that the second command is again trying to downloading java6 and related stuff, like below.

```
root@richard-vb:~# docker pull dockerinaction/ch3_myapp
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from dockerinaction/ch3_myapp
193224d99eda: Pull complete
a3ed95caeb02: Pull complete
d5e87c275989: Pull complete
bb8d9a5ecc4e: Pull complete
7490d74f238e: Pull complete
021438acd8d7: Pull complete
4078d18de562: Pull complete
ce37551720d0: Pull complete
d5f21dfddee2: Pull complete
e0d9390e29cd: Pull complete
285eb2cbce99: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:73bbafb618a24ff171b50fb5796d87a8b4190699bc6d500597bd67d51e3f81dc
Status: Downloaded newer image for dockerinaction/ch3_myapp:latest

root@richard-vb:~# docker pull dockerinaction/ch3_myotherapp
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from dockerinaction/ch3_myotherapp
193224d99eda: Already exists
a3ed95caeb02: Pull complete
b2cc8f1bc9d6: Pull complete
bb8d9a5ecc4e: Pull complete
7490d74f238e: Pull complete
021438acd8d7: Pull complete
e4c4e5255cbb: Pull complete
a030b8e169aa: Pull complete
c318611236ca: Pull complete
a994304b5bce: Pull complete
3bc3fe12e21b: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:4abb3cbaf8793034df4edb47c16ef5c22820ba5d0f120fd21864c8cc0b578957
Status: Downloaded newer image for dockerinaction/ch3_myotherapp:latest
```

I notice **193224d99eda: Already exists** in the second command, but I expect all layers should 'Already exists'. Actually I can see "downloading" and "extracting" progress bar when running the second command. And even worse, why the layers look different for the two commands when the Dockerfiles look the same?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you in windows? This could be the explanation of rare behaviors in docker.

Comment: @JRichardsz well, it's ubuntu in VirtualBox in windows

Comment: Try this: clean your machine with docker system prune and check if dockerinaction/ch3_myapp exists before exec docker pull dockerinaction/ch3_myotherapp. Dependencies already downloaded them are one of the fundamentals of docker and works as espected

Answer (score 1):

It's normal: `Dockerfile`s are the same, the **Docker context (files being used during the build) are different**: instructions `COPY . /example` have copied different files.

For example:

- `ch3_myapp` is using [`ch3_myapp` java file](https://github.com/dockerinaction/ch3_myapp/blob/master/j6/Main.java)
- `ch3_myotherapp` is using [`ch3_myotherapp` java file](https://github.com/dockerinaction/ch3_myotherapp/blob/master/Main.java)

These files being different, the layer created by `COPY . /example` will be different as well as all subsequent layers - thus the different in your `docker pull` logs.

For more details on the build context, you can refer to the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#extended-description).